# Get data from selected row of gtk treeview - gtkmm, c++

Tags: c++, treeview, gtk, selection, gtkmm

I have a GTK application that has a window with a `treeview` and a button. When the button is clicked I need to get the data from the first (and only) column of the selected row in the `treeview`.

This is the class for the columns:

```
class ModelColumns: 
public Gtk::TreeModel::ColumnRecord{
    public:

    ModelColumns(){ add(m_port_name); }

    Gtk::TreeModelColumn<Glib::ustring> m_port_name;
};
```

This is like in the example here but with only one column: http://www.lugod.org/presentations/gtkmm/treeview.html

This is the button click signal handler at the moment:

`tvPorts` is the `treeview` widget

`tvPortsList` is the `listStore` for the `treeview`

```
static
void on_btnPortSelectOK_clicked (){
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::TreeSelection> selection = tvPorts->get_selection();
    Gtk::TreeModel::iterator selectedRow = selection->get_selected();
    //Now what?
    //Need to get data from selected row to display it.
}
```

I have searched the documentation and many examples to try and find out what to do next but can't find any examples for gtkmm, I can only find examples for c or python implementations.

As far as I can tell, I need to get a `TreeRow` object from my `iterator` (`selectedRow`) how do I do this?

Thanks.

---

**Update:**

I am now using this code and it almost works.
The only problem is that it prints the previous selection.
The first time I select something and then press the button it prints only a new line. The second time it prints what was selected the first time, the third prints the second, etc.

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::TreeSelection> selection = tvPorts->get_selection();
Gtk::TreeModel::iterator selectedRow = selection->get_selected();
Gtk::TreeModel::Row row = *selectedRow;
Glib::ustring port = row.get_value(m_Columns.m_port_name);
printf("\nselected port: %s", port.data());
```

This seems odd.
(`m_Columns` is an instance of the `ModelColumns` class)

---

**Update 2:**

Fixed the problem by adding `fflush(stdout);`
It all works now, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1TreeRow.html) say to simply dereference the iter to get the TreeRow:

```
Gtk::TreeModel::Row row = *iter;   // 'iter' being your 'selectedRow'
std::cout<<row[0];
```

Comment: This has helped so much, thanks. There is a small problem though, mentioned in the Update in the question.

Comment: Got it, stdout wasn't flushing properly. Thanks for the help.