# Gtk: How to add a click event to a CellRendererPixbuf in a Treeview?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtktreeview

I want to get a signal event if somebody click my pixbuf image? How is this possible.

```
treestore = Gtk.TreeStore()
...
treeview = Gtk.TreeView()
treeview.set_model(self.treestore)

renderer_pixbuf = Gtk.CellRendererPixbuf()
renderer_pixbuf.props.icon_name = 'list-add'
renderer_pixbuf.connect("clicked", self.start_event)  # doesn't work

column_pixbuf = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Label", renderer_pixbuf)
treeview.append_column(column_pixbuf)
```

So what is the right way to get this feature?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wrong, but I think this is only one question.

Comment: So what is the question, how to add a button to a treeview? Or how to connect to a pixbuf clicked signal?

Comment: How to connect a pixbuf clicked signal. I removed the other sentence.

Comment: If you are trying to use buttons (or equivalent) in a treeview row, you might want to realize that it is discouraged. See [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1009065.html) or even one of my other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050975/adding-gtkbutton-to-gtkliststore-with-text-in-gtk).